# Why is this merge sort algorithm in Java printing random output and not sorting the Arraylist?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, merge

I'm trying to implement the merge sort algorithm in Java but keep getting random outputs possibly due to a recursion error. Below is the code which is causing the issue.

Thanks.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Merging {
    private static ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collections.addAll(numbers,7,6,3,1,9,8);
        mergeSort(numbers);
        for (int x: numbers){
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
    public static void mergeSort(ArrayList<Integer> numbers){
        // System.out.println(numbers.size());
        if (numbers.size()>1){
            int mid = (numbers.size()%2==0 ? numbers.size()/2 : ((int)Math.floor(numbers.size()/2)));
            //System.out.println(mid);
            ArrayList<Integer> left=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            ArrayList<Integer> right=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i=0;i<mid;i++){
                left.add(numbers.get(i));
            }
            for (int i=mid;i<numbers.size();i++){
                right.add(numbers.get(i));
            }
            mergeSort(left);
            mergeSort(right);
            int i,j;
            i=j=0;
            while (i<left.size() && j<right.size()){
                if (left.get(i)<=right.get(j)){
                    numbers.add(left.get(i));
                    i+=1;
                }else{
                    numbers.add(right.get(j));
                    j+=1;
                }
            }
            while (i<left.size()){
                numbers.add(left.get(i));
                i+=1;
            }
            while (j<right.size()){
                numbers.add(right.get(j));
                j+=1;
            }
        }
    }        
}`
```

I've tried modifying the mid variable in a few ways and logged outputs but nothing has helped in solving it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the algorithm you wrote was that when it went to merge things the `numbers` List wasn't an empty List.  Therefore, calling `add` was expanding the numbers array with duplicates from `left` and `right`.  I'd suggest calling `numbers.clear()` before you start the merging process, or use `List.set` to overwrite what number is at each location.  If you did something like this:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
for( int k = 0; k < numbers.size(); k++ ) {
    if( j < right.size() && i < left.size() ) {
       if( left.get(i) < right.get(j) ) {
           numbers.set(k, left.get(i));
           i++;
       } else {
           numbers.set(k, right.get(j));
           j++;
       }
    } else if( i < left.size() ) {
       numbers.set( k, left.get(i) );
       i++;
    } else if( j < right.size() ) {
       numbers.set( k, right.get(j) );
       j++;
    }
}
```

That cleans it up a bit by making it happen in a single loop.

When creating left and right here is a simple one line way to copy List:

```
List<Integer> left = new ArrayList<>( numbers.subList( 0, mid ) );
List<Integer> right = new ArrayList<>( numbers.subList( mid, numbers.size() );
```

I'd suggest printing out the array on each call of mergeSort so you can see what the algorithm is doing:

```
public void printArray( List<Integer> arr ) {
   System.out.print("[ ");
   boolean first = true;
   for( Integer i : arr ) {
      if( !first ) print(", ")
      System.out.print( i );
      first = false;
   }
   System.out.println(" ]");
}
```

Also understand the relation between `java.util.List` and `java.util.ArrayList`, and make effective use of `List` where you can (pretty much everywhere).  This isn't a merge sort thing, but an important step in understanding Java.

Comment: You are correct I mixed up my data structures.  With Linked List is can be done in place, but arrays it'll be a copy.   I've modified the answer to reflect that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Ok :-) It can also be done with arrays, but as far as I know, the known ways to do that are inefficient so they're not typically used.

Comment: There are ways to reduce all of the copying, but it's more complicated than the algorithm he's trying to get working so it was bad advice.